# Multiple conditions on pattern in sed

Tags: sed

**test.sed**

```
s/^(\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\))\([[:space:]][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/(XXX)\2-\3/
```

**Command I used to run test.sed:**

> sed -f test.sed file.txt

**file.txt:**

```
(123) 123-2345
(456) 416-2345
(111) 905-2345
(222) 905-2345
```

**Output:**

```
(XXX) 123-2345
(XXX) 416-2345
(XXX) 905-2345
(XXX) 905-2345
```

**Expected Output:**

```
(XXX) 123-2345
(XXX) 416-2345
(ZZZ) 905-2345
(ZZZ) 905-2345
```

Hello, basically this just change all phone number to form like "(XXX) 123-1234".
But I want to put one more condition that It will not change numbers in parenthesis to XXX but to ZZZ if original numbers in the parenthesis was 111 or 222.

How can I do this in sed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/\((111|222)\)/(ZZZ)/;s/\([0-9]{3}\)/(XXX)/' file.txt
```